# How to ensure that the invariant culture is used in all Visual Studio unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, culture

Our solution is used by developers both in a "decimal comma" and a "decimal point" locale. We use the built in unit test engine of Visual Studio. How can I assure that the tests use the invariant culture in both locales without having to resort to inserting `IFormatProviders` all over the place? This is to prevent that all tests that check the result of a computation using a `string.Format` of a floating point number to fail in one of our locales.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common base class for all unit-tests and in setup set thread's current culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

(common setup from a base fixture works both in MSTest and NUnit).

If your code can spawn new threads you can additionally [set the default culture for new threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx) (requires .NET 4.5):

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```